# How do I know how big a Windows app download will be?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-store-app

I've just got a Windows 8.1 laptop (today) so it wants to download some app updates. I'm used to the Android (phone) and Apple (iPad) app stores telling you beforehand how big the downloads will be. Where do I find this information for the Windows app store?

Yes, I'm aware that I'm using a majorly different OS on each device!

Answer (score -1):

From the Start menu type "App Sizes" (without the quotes) and the window will show you the existing apps on your machine. You will notice that they are quite small. Download and update with confidence! Most computer hard drives today have tons of room for that sort of thing....unless it's a tablet with a tiny SSD or something.

Comment: I'm worried about using my data allowance, not how much room it will take up on the disc. An app that is "quite small" could end up costing me if I'm not careful!

Comment: May I also say after 59 minutes experience with Windows 8.1 that I HATE MICROSOFT!

Comment: Also, since I am updating, not installing additional apps yet, the size on disc should be roughly the same as the previous version.